# How to show busy icon when leaflet api load tile images

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet

i like to know is there any way exist in leaflet api which i can fire when it load tile and when tile loading finish then another function will be called.

i was reading leaflet api and found in this url http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer

there is two event exist called `loading and load` which may solve my purpose.
basically i want to show busy icon when map api will load tiles and i want to hide busy icon when loading will be completed.

but i do not find any sample code like how to attached these event called `loading and load` with my map api. so it will be helpful if some one show me how to attached this two function `loading and load` with map api. if possible please attach a jsfiddle link in answer. thanks

### The below code i got from @sigon. so thanks to @sigon

```
<div id="map"></div>

html, body, #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


var map = new L.Map('map').setView([55, 0], 3);
var basemap = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  maxZoom: 19
});

map.addLayer(basemap);

basemap.on('loading', function (event) {
   console.log('start loading tiles');
});
basemap.on('load', function (event) {
   console.log('all tiles loaded');
});
basemap.on('tileloadstart', function (event) {
   console.log('start loading 1 tile');
});
```

Comment: There is a plugin already built for this purpose - https://github.com/ebrelsford/Leaflet.loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var basemap = new 
  L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
});

basemap.on('loading', function (event) {
  console.log('start loading tiles');
});
basemap.on('load', function (event) {
  console.log('all tiles loaded');
});
```

Edit:
I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5gsfoyx/5/)

Comment: thanks and i update my post with your code taken from jsfiddle. thanks